# Jquery Slide up and Slide down toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working with ASP.NET MVC 4. I have a nested list in my razor view like so:

```
<ul class="nav" id="product-cat-menu">
    <li><a href="/Products/Index?category=2002">Dental <i class="fa fa-plus-square-o rightdown"></i></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/Products/Index?category=2004">Materials <i class="fa fa-plus-square-o rightdown"></i></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/Products/Index?category=2011">Pulp<i class="fa fa-plus-square-o rightdown"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Products/Index?category=3011">Etchants <i class="fa fa-plus-square-o rightdown"></i></a>
                </ul>
                <li><a href="/Products/Index?category=2006">Medicines <i class="fa fa-plus-square-o rightdown"></i></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="/Products/Index?category=2011">Pulp<i class="fa fa-plus-square-o rightdown"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="/Products/Index?category=3011">Etchants <i class="fa fa-plus-square-o rightdown"></i></a>
                    </ul>
                </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/Products/Index?category=2003">Oral <i class="fa fa-plus-square-o rightdown"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

And the main CSS is:

```
#product-cat-menu li {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
}

#product-cat-menu li .rightdown {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}

#product-cat-menu ul {
    display: none;
}

#product-cat-menu li ul li {
    padding: 5px 0 5px 25px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

And jQuery is like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#product-cat-menu a").click(function () {
        $("#product-cat-menu ul").slideUp();
        if (!$(this).next().is(":visible")) {
            $(this).next().slideDown();
        }
    });
});
```

The problem is that when clicking on the `li` it slides down the child list but after going to the controller action it is slides up. I want show the slide down part after the page refreshing.

For that i am trying the following code also:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#product-cat-menu a .rightdown").click(function() {
        //...........
    });
});
```

but this is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to prevent the default behaviour of the html anchor tag (`<a>`) occurring.

The line that is missing is:

`evt.preventDefault();`

The full code example is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#product-cat-menu a").click(function (evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        $("#product-cat-menu ul").slideUp();
        if (!$(this).next().is(":visible")) {
            $(this).next().slideDown();
        }
    });
});
```

You can see this in a JSFiddle here: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4rdhpL3z/)**

Comment: i have one more doubt, when clicking on List Materials or Medicine, then list is slide up, i want to slide down next ul inside this loop...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by this, can you explain it more.